# Convert SQL Server code to Oracle please?

Tags: sql, oracle

Having a bit of a issue with a SQL conversion from SQL Server to Oracle.

We are passing in a datetime value (in this example just 1900-01-01) and we need to select all rows that have a modified date greater than 2 days before the date passsed in. Here is the SQL syntax that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLENAME
WHERE  CAST(LAST_MODIFIED AS DATE) > CAST(DATEADD(dd, -2, '1990-01-01') AS DATE);
```

Where `LAST_MODIFIED` is a column, and the `'1900-01-01'` is a value being injected to the SQL String in C# prior to it being executed. Before being asked, we prefer not to subtract the 2 days from the date before passing it to the SQL :)

So what we need then is just the above query converted to Oracle syntax... We have tried a couple things and it fails :(

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this in Oracle as:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE TRUNC(LAST_MODIFIED) > (DATE '1990-01-01') - 2
```

Notes:

- In Oracle, `DATE` includes a time component, so casting to a date does nothing.
- Oracle supports various ways to include a date/time constant.  I prefer the keyword `DATE` with the ISO/ANSI standard date format YYYY-MM-DD.
- The `- 2` is perhaps more accurately written as `- interval '2' day`.  However, the interval notation is new(ish) to Oracle.

And, it is better in either database to write this without modifying `last_modified_date`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE LAST_MODIFIED >= (DATE '1990-01-01') - 1
```

Removing the time component is not needed, with the right date comparison.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLENAME
WHERE  CAST(LAST_MODIFIED AS DATE) > TO_DATE('1990-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')-2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLENAME
WHERE  TRUNC( LAST_MODIFIED ) > TO_DATE( '1990-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) - 2;
```

or, if you pass the value in using the `:date_value` bind variable:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLENAME
WHERE  TRUNC( LAST_MODIFIED ) > :date_value - 2;
```

If the value you are passing in to the query does not have a time component then you can just do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLENAME
WHERE  LAST_MODIFIED >= :date_value - 1;
```